# Simple to use VPN Firewall

Tags: firewall, router, cisco-vpn

In my company we use a Cisco ASA 5505 Router with the VPN, Firewall setup, and we route IP and VOIP traffic through it. I can only log into the router from a single computer due to the quirkiness of the ASDM application and Java. And when I am logged in, I only understand about 30-40% of what I am seeing. I am not unfamiliar with how firewalls work, but as a developer and not a sysadmin, I am very far from comfortable with most networking devices. As such, we have a third party company that manages the router for us.

I worry about what happens should we end that relationship, Likewise, the inability to easily log in and maange the router worries me.

Is there a router on the market that people can recommend that would be easy to use by someone with a passing knowledge such as myself, and manage the same level and types of traffic that the Cisco ASA5505 does?

Comment: Sorry, man.  Product recommendations are off-topic.  As are learning material recommendations.  They're off-topic because they attract spammy, opinionated, and otherwise poor-quality answers, not, you know, to be mean or whatever.  I think it's a legitimate question, but it's not a good fit for Server Fault.

Comment: Sounds like an Apple AirPort Extreme is just what the Dr ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise-level products, like Cisco's, are designed and built for a professional market; as such, their customers are expected to know and undertand what they are doing and how to properly manage them. There are lots and lots of "simpler" products out there, but they are nowhere near the levels of performance, reliability and flexibility you can expect from an enterprise-level device.

You question just doesn't make sense. You can pick up home and SOHO routers everywhere, but complaining about an ASA being too complex and difficult to manage only shows you shouldn't be managing it, unless you are willing to actually learn how it should be done.

As for the side question, if a "simpler" router (and which one) could be enough for your company network: this is completely off topic here, and also utterly unanswerable without a thorough assessment of your business needs.

Comment: thank you for you learned opinion. It is refreshing to know that the internet is not littered with individuals encumbered by politeness and courtesy. I am honored that you actually took time out of your busy day to write three whole paragraphs to complain about a question that is "silly" and could have been easily ignored by you.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude or anything; but this is a Q&A site aimed to *professionals*, and you just posted a question stating "this product is too complex for me and I want a simpler one", without any real information about why it's not appropriate for your needs and what a more appropriate product would be; and, even if this was the case, the question would still have been off topic, as per the site topic definition.